# How can I optimize Largest Prime factor in given Number?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

**Constraints**

1<=T<=10

10<=N<=10^2

**Input**

2

10

17

**Output**

5

17

**This is my code**

```
n=int(input())
for f in range(n):
    b=[]
    a=int(input())
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if i>1:
            for j in range(2,i):
                if (i%j)==0:
                    break
            else:
                if a%i==0:

                     b.append(i)
    print(max(b))
```

**Explanation**

10 are **{2,5}**, so answer **5**

17 is 17 itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the Constraints,
if T means there are at most 10 test cases,
and N means the range of the given number is between 10 to 100,

One of the most optimized ways is to create an initialized list in the code and print the pre-computed answer for every input read. :)

```
answer = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2, 3,
      5, 11, 3, 13, 7, 5, 2, 17, 3, 19,
      5, 7, 11, 23, 3, 5, 13, 3, 7, 29,
      5, 31, 2, 11, 17, 7, 3, 37, 19, 13,
      5, 41, 7, 43, 11, 5, 23, 47, 3, 7,
      5, 17, 13, 53, 3, 11, 7, 19, 29, 59,
      5, 61, 31, 7, 2, 13, 11, 67, 17, 23,
      7, 71, 3, 73, 37, 5, 19, 11, 13, 79,
      5, 3, 41, 83, 7, 17, 43, 29, 11, 89,
      5, 13, 23, 31, 47, 19, 3, 97, 7, 11, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of primes under 100.

Run a loop for each 'i' starting from 'a' to 'a/2-1' only, and check if 'i' divides 'a' completely and is present in 'primes'.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

n=int(input())
for f in range(n):
    a=int(input())
    for i in range(a,int(a/2-1),-1):
        if(a%i==0 and i in primes):
          print(i)
          break
```

If you dont want to create list of primes manually, you can use this first to create primes list through for loop:

```
import math

def isPrime(n): 
      
    if (n <= 1): 
        return False
    
    #check from sqrt(n) to 2
    for i in range(int(math.sqrt(n)),1,-1): 
        if (n % i == 0): 
            return False
  
    return True

primes = []
for i in range(100):
  if(isPrime(i)):
    primes.append(i)

n=int(input())
for f in range(n):
    a=int(input())
    for i in range(a,int(a/2-1),-1):
        if(a%i==0 and i in primes):
          print(i)
          break
```

Comment: Without creating list of primes..?

Comment: It s usually a trade off between first computing the primes list and then using that list to check if element is present in it or not, or you can check if number is prime by calling isPrime() function above. As in your cases, both N and T are small, you can use any of the 2 approaches.

Comment: I am still getting **Timeout** Error